# How to get a $haystack trimmed using a $needle?

Tags: php

There are many functions to split a string using a needle, what is the smartest (shortest) way?

```
$haystack="/this/is/the/haystack/string/to/be/trimmed/using/a/needle/string/";
$needle="to/be/";
```

result required is

> /this/is/the/haystack/string/

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = explode($needle, $haystack);
$first_part = $result[0];
```

Example: http://codepad.org/OXvf4O6A

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this, it is not necessarily the *shortest* way (I'm sure there are shorter ways) but it is reasonably concise, readable and efficient:

```
$newStr = substr($haystack, 0, strpos($haystack, $needle));
```

[**Demo.**](http://ideone.com/pZpTY)